# pywinauto with a popup window

Tags: python, pywinauto

Im working through pywinauto, not a great developer but I can write some of the basics in python.  Im getting hung up though.  I have a popup that is causing me to not be able to press ok on and really not sure what direction I need to look

Really a two part question:

1. How can I move over to this popup IF it occurs, this wont always be the case as sometimes those files may not exist.

- I tried using app.Confirm.Ok.click() and also app.Confirm.type('{ENTER}') neither worked.

2. How can I add in variables that I could call from an external .txt file for things like the "localhost" I included there in my code?

Code here:

```
from pywinauto import application
import time
app = application.Application()
app.start("Install.exe")
app.SelectLanguage.Ok.click()
app.Platform.Iacceptthetermsinthelicenseagreement.click()
app.Platform.Next.click()
app.Platform.Next.click()
app.PlatformInstallationOptions.Next.click()
app.PlatformSpecifyCertifcate.comboBox.select(0)
app.PlatformSpecifyCertifcate.Next.click()
app.PlatformConfigurationDatabaseOptions.type_keys('{TAB}')
app.PlatformConfigurationDatabaseOptions.type_keys('{TAB}')
app.PlatformConfigurationDatabaseOptions.type_keys('localhost')
app.PlatformConfigurationDatabaseOptions.type_keys('{TAB}')
app.PlatformConfigurationDatabaseOptions.type_keys('{SPACE}')
app.PlatformConfigurationDatabaseOptions.type_keys('{TAB}')
app.PlatformConfigurationDatabaseOptions.type_keys('Config')
app.PlatformConfigurationDatabaseOptions.Next.click()
app.PlatformSpecifyHTTPSBindingCertifcate.type_keys('{TAB}')
app.PlatformSpecifyHTTPSBindingCertifcate.type_keys('{TAB}')
app.PlatformSpecifyHTTPSBindingCertifcate.type_keys('{RIGHT}')
app.PlatformSpecifyHTTPSBindingCertifcate.type_keys('{SPACE}')
app.PlatformSpecifyHTTPSBindingCertifcate.Next.click() 
app.PlatformAdvancedWorkflowSettings.Next.click() 
app.PlatformPlatformLanguage.Next.click()
app.PlatformInstanceDatabaseOptions.type_keys('{TAB}')
app.PlatformInstanceDatabaseOptions.type_keys('{TAB}')
app.PlatformInstanceDatabaseOptions.type_keys('localhost')
app.PlatformInstanceDatabaseOptions.type_keys('{TAB}')
app.PlatformInstanceDatabaseOptions.type_keys('{SPACE}')
app.PlatformInstanceDatabaseOptions.type_keys('{TAB}')
app.PlatformInstanceDatabaseOptions.type_keys('Instance')
app.PlatformInstanceDatabaseOptions.Next.click()
app.PlatformTimeZone.Next.click()
app.WebApplicationOptions.type_keys('{TAB}')
app.WebApplicationOptions.type_keys('{TAB}')
app.WebApplicationOptions.type_keys('{TAB}')
app.WebApplicationOptions.type_keys('{TAB}')
app.WebApplicationOptions.type_keys('{UP}')
app.WebApplicationOptions.Next.click()

app.WebApplicationOptions.type_keys('{ENTER}')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
confirmWin = .app.window(title_re = u'Confirm') #Check your window header object name.
# Use timeout based on average pop up time in your application.
if confirmWin.exists(timeout=10, retry_interval=1): 
    confirmWin.set_focus()
    yesBtn = confirmWin[u'&Yes'] 
    # Check the object name of the Yes button. You can use Swapy tool(It is deprecated but it works, else you can use inspect.exe)
    yesBtn.click()
else:
    print('Confirmation pop up did not appear')
```

This should work :)